# Where is Warworld?

Tags: westworld-2016

In episode 2 of *Westworld* season 3 we are introduced possibly for the first time to Warworld. Where is this Warworld located? Can someone answer this in relation to Park 4 in the sense that how far is Warworld from park 4? Does Warworld even exist physically or is it just a simulation too?

Comment: Previously drifting across space as Mongul and Sinestro would see fit, currently destroyed. ... What do you mean, wrong universe?!

Comment: @Jenayah Mongul? Sinestro? I am asking about _Westworld_ TV series. I think you're talking about different universe.

Comment: yes, that was the joke... There's a planet-ship called Warworld in the DC universe. That's what I was referring to

Comment: Has anyone checked the Warworld beaches? If you find the top bit of the Statue of Liberty poking up through the sand, then you know what's going on.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Are you implying that they blew it up? The maniacs!

Comment: @Z.Cochrane _THEY BLEW IT ALL TO HELL_ *[wave arms a bit]*

Answer (score 1):

There is no evidence in the show that it exists anywhere other than simulation, but we can speculate. In Season 2, it is revealed that one of the functions of The Cradle is to simulate new narratives, and inside The Cradle it appears as an exact replica of Sweetwater. The apparatus Maeve finds herself in is very similar to The Cradle. So assuming they didn't create that entire world for the benefit of Maeve, Warworld could be an existing or upcoming Delos park.